# Why should I use TCP Client and TCP Listener?

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to do some research on tcp client and tcp listener in c# for a microsoft exam.  I've found quite a lot on the internet about how to use them, but very little about *why* I should use them.

I've discovered that it's a secure way of communicating between 2 applications, but I don't get why I should use tcp instead of (for example) just exposing a method on one application and calling it from the other.

Does anyone know of any good webpages that might be able to explain this to me?

Comment: If the 2 applications are running on different machines, you can't just call a method on one from the other.

Comment: If you want to understand why TCP is safe, compare it to UDP. In short, TCP uses "ping pong" verification, while UDP send data and doesn't care if it has been received or not.

Comment: If they really are two apps - running in separate processes, then HOW would you implement "exposing a method on one application and calling it from the other"? It can be done; it's not necessarily easy or clean or secure and will in fact use a TCP socket under the hood.

Comment: TCP is not *secure*, it's only *reliable* (for a suitable definition of reliable). It also has congestion control mechanisms preventing the applications from overloading the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to *communicate* between applications with in a system you can use any inter process communication methods. But if you intend to have two applications running in different machines than you need a mechanism outside of `IPC`. This is where TCP and UDP come into picture.

TCP/UDP are elaborate protocols(rules) that govern how the two applications connect, exchange data and terminate the connection. (UDP , does not have the connect/terminating phase, BTW.)

Its interesting. Start with Wiki.

Most start socket programming with this well known page (In 'C' though) - http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/